# Why does this Ruby if/else/end block require one "end" less than I think it should?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, unix

I'm developing Rails apps for quite some years now already on Mac OS X.

A co-worker now wants to learn Ruby and Rails, and he's using Windows. Everything seems to work quite fine so far, but from time to time, Ruby behaves strange.

The current example is the following. Ruby on Windows complains about one `end` too much with the following code:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def update
    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
end
```

When I remove one `end` like so:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def update
    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'edit'
    # <- no end here!
  end
end
```

...everything seems to work fine. But in my opinion this is completely wrong, isn't it? Do I miss something? Are there key differences between Ruby on Windows and UNIX?

Comment: Running some similar sudo-code on my windows machine (ruby 2.0.0p451) gives me an error if I neglect the end. Is this a direct copy of your code? Perhaps post the whole file in case there is some context switching going on

Comment: The error is probably in some other part of the code in this file. The code you posted above is fine and valid Ruby. However, due to the parsing rules, Ruby sometimes complains about a missing (or superfluous) end and a location rather far away from the actual error.

Comment: It's probably somewhere else in the code. Have you included modules?

Comment: I will try to put the stuff on GitHub so you'll have the full context.

Comment: Could it also be a copy&paste problem? The code originally comes from the Ruby on Rails tutorial, and my co-worker copy&pastes the codes from Internet Explorer to his editor. Any possible problems here like non breaking space or so?